# Writing a class to hold Arduino Properties for an Arduino I2C Debugger

Tags: python, object-oriented, properties, serial-port, arduino

I have this class which mostly holds a bunch of properties and their setters. I also have wrappers for some functions of another module. Here is the class:

```
class ARCArduino(object):
    """
    Class to manage Arduino functionality
    """

    def __init__(self, tree_item, port, identifier):
        self.__i2c = ArduinoI2C()
        self.__i2c.setPort(port)
        self.__i2c.connectPort()
        self.__id = None
        self.__i2c_version = None
        self.__switch_version = None
        self.__tree_item = tree_item
        self.__address_list = []
        self.__port = port
        self.__identifier = identifier

    @property
    def id(self):
        if self.__id is None:
            try:
                self.__id = self.__i2c.getID()
            except IOError:
                self.__id = "NO CONNECTION"
        return self.__id

    @property
    def i2c_version(self):
        if self.__i2c_version is None:
            try:
                self.__i2c_version = self.__i2c.i2cVersion()
            except IOError:
                self.__i2c_version = "NO CONNECTION"
        return self.__i2c_version

    @property
    def switch_version(self):
        if self.__switch_version is None:
            try:
                self.__switch_version = self.__i2c.switchVersion()
            except IOError:
                self.__switch_version = "NO CONNECTION"
        return self.__switch_version

    @property
    def tree_item(self):
        return self.__tree_item

    @tree_item.setter
    def tree_item(self, item):
        if type(item) is not wx.TreeItemId:
            return
        self.__tree_item = item

    @property
    def address_list(self):
        return self.__address_list

    @address_list.setter
    def address_list(self, addr_list):
        if type(addr_list) is not list:
            return
        self.__address_list = addr_list

    @property
    def port(self):
        return self.__port

    @port.setter
    def port(self, port):
        if port[:3] != "COM":
            return
        self.__port = port

    @property
    def identifier(self):
        return self.__identifier

    @identifier.setter
    def identifier(self, letter):
        if type(letter) is not str:
            return
        if letter[-1] != ':':
            letter += ':'
        self.__identifier = letter

    def serialCommand(self, command):
        """
        Wrapper for ArduinoI2C serialCommand function
        """
        return self.__i2c.serialCommand(command)

    def close(self):
        self.__i2c.close()

    def connectPort(self):
        self.__i2c.connectPort()
```

This implementation feels a little dumb to me. Is there a more elegant way to implement something like this?

Here is some further clarification on the functionality of the class:

`self.__i2c` is an instance of an Arduino I2C communication module that was internally developed at my company. It allows users to send commands to I2C devices over the Arduino's I2C bus. `setPort` and `connectPort` are setting and connect a COM port for the specific Arduino.

`self.__id` is a serial number generated for the Arduino from a company-MySQL database. It is set elsewhere in the program.

`self.__switch_version` and `self.__i2c_version` are two floats stored on the Arduino that are the version number of some software running on the Arduino.

`self.__tree_item` is a `wx.TreeItemId` (I believe it's stored as just an int) that is the id of the `wx.TreeItem` stored in a `wx.TreeCtrl` elsewhere in the program.

`self.__address_list` is a list of ints which are the I2C addresses of devices discovered on the Arduino's I2C bus.

`self.__port` is a string which holds the COM port the Arduino is inserted in.

`self.__identifier` is a letter which identifies the Arduino elsewhere in the program. The program expects the user has multiple Arduinos concurrently being used, so a letter is a quick shorthand to easily identify them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some feedback I have. I haven't had a chance to work with Arduino much, but there are some things that stand out to me:

```
 # Nothing to glaring in your constructor, but some tidbits:
 # I might add some defaults. 
 # I also noticed you have a lot of items in your constructor. 
 # Maybe **kwargs is warranted.

def __init__(self, tree_item, port=8080, identifier):

or

def __init__(self, **kwargs)

    # the number of arguments is borderline imho. I usually find if I
    # have too large a number (subjective), there is opportunity to 
    # break out the code into more classes. 
    self.__i2c = ArduinoI2C()
    self.__i2c.setPort(port)
    self.__i2c.connectPort()
    self.__id = None
    self.__i2c_version = None
    self.__switch_version = None
    self.__tree_item = tree_item
    self.__address_list = []
    self.__port = port
    self.__identifier = identifier


# Typically methods indicate some sort of action. i.e. get_id, show_id.
# specifying a noun is usually grounds for a class/instance variable.
# I would consider renaming your method to "def get_id(self):"
@property
def id(self):
    if self.__id is None:
        try:
            self.__id = self.__i2c.getID()
        except IOError: 
        # It may be good to add some logging. 
        # python logging module is great.
            self.__id = "NO CONNECTION"
    return self.__id

# ditto method name
@property
def i2c_version(self):
    if self.__i2c_version is None:
        try:
            self.__i2c_version = self.__i2c.i2cVersion()
        except IOError:
        # ditton on the logging.
            self.__i2c_version = "NO CONNECTION"
    return self.__i2c_version

# ditto method name
@property
def switch_version(self):
    if self.__switch_version is None:
        try:
            self.__switch_version = self.__i2c.switchVersion()
        except IOError:
            self.__switch_version = "NO CONNECTION"
    return self.__switch_version

# ditto method name
@property
def tree_item(self):
    return self.__tree_item

# ditto method name
@tree_item.setter
def tree_item(self, item):
    if type(item) is not wx.TreeItemId:
        return
    self.__tree_item = item

# ditto method name
@property
def address_list(self):
    return self.__address_list

# ditto method name
@address_list.setter
def address_list(self, addr_list):
    if type(addr_list) is not list:
        return
    self.__address_list = addr_list

# ditto method name
@property
def port(self):
    return self.__port

# ditto method name
@port.setter
def port(self, port):
    if port[:3] != "COM":
        return
    self.__port = port

# ditto method name
@property
def identifier(self):
    return self.__identifier

# ditto method name
@identifier.setter
def identifier(self, letter):
    if type(letter) is not str:
        return
    if letter[-1] != ':':
        letter += ':'
    self.__identifier = letter

# ditto, and its not idiomatic to use camelCase in a method name.
#   def run_serial_command(self, command)
def serialCommand(self, command):
    """
    Wrapper for ArduinoI2C serialCommand function
    """
    return self.__i2c.serialCommand(command)

# this method name is ok
def close(self):
    self.__i2c.close()

# this one two.. ditch the camelCase for snake_case connect_port
def connectPort(self):
    self.__i2c.connectPort()
```

It looks like there might be some opportunity for grouping your commands into separate classes, however not sure if you have enough per group yet.

i.e.

```
class ArduinoVersions(ARCArduino):

# this might be to ambiguous, but just trying to give the general idea.
class ArduinoProperties(ArcaArduino):
```

I have a feeling your command set will grow, so breaking this out may provide better organization in the future.

Comment: For the functions where you say change them to "get_id" or something along those lines, I thought that when creating an attribute with the `@property` decorator, the method name had to be the name of the intended attribute. Also for the `serialCommand` and `connectPort` methods, they're meant to shadow existing commands in the `ArduinoI2C` library, so an ARCArduino object can be used similarly to an ArduinoI2C object.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, haven't logged in for a while. You are 100% correct on @property. Miss on my part. I blame lack of sleep.. :-) Your reasons on the other methods may be valid as well, however the potential confusion (imho) is the method names will need a double take as camelCase is a convention typically reserved for class names (or if following an existing convention). If I were looking at your code for the 1st time, I most likely would miss the arduino lib correlation. [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#overriding-principle) (See class/method/function conventions)